# Best schedule task technique for daily database update

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks

My app needs to update the local database daily, it makes calls to a public repository requesting for the latest added/modified items or for items added/modified since the last time the database in the device was updated. There are several techniques, like the use of: AlarmManager, jobDispatcher, JobScheduler, SynchAdapter, every API has pros and cons: low CPU usage (Good), it wakes the app (not ideal), can be canceled by the OS to free resources (Not good).

What is the best way to update daily, with some conditions:

-The update should execute even if the app is closed.

-The update should execute during a time range (00:00 to 05:00).

-Can update if the device is connected thru wifi.

-Battery charge above 50%.

-It doesn't need to wake the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Android-Job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) library provided by `evernote`. Its easy to use. It use either the `JobScheduler, GcmNetworkManager` or `AlarmManager`. Its works back to Ice Cream Sandwich. Depending on your requirements, this library decides which API suits your job.

This library has some advance feature like you can specify a required network connection, charging state, periodic execution.

Check [this](https://blog.evernote.com/tech/2015/10/26/unified-job-library-android/) blog post too.